# variable from callback is sometimes empty

Tags: javascript, callback

I have an function which returns an random color in an callback, like this:

```
function getRandomColor(callback) {

    var colors = [
        'greyblue',
        'lightblue',
        'blue',
        'lightgreen',
        'darkgreen',
        'purple',
        'pink',
        'red',
        'yellow',
        'brown'
    ];

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length+1);
    var color = colors[random];

    return callback(color);
}
```

This function is called in an other function which needs the value from the callback. But `color` from the callback is sometimes empty. Can anybody explain why this is happening? I use an callback to prevent an empty value actually but it looks like it's not an waterproof solution.

```
function createCategory(name, access_token, callback){
    getRandomColor(function(color){
        countr.callApi(
            {
                url: 'categories', 
                method: 'POST'
            }, {
                name: name, 
                visible: true, 
                color: color 
            }, 
            access_token, 
            function(err, category){
                return callback(err, category);
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Since the API where are using is requiring an color on an category (which we want to create) this call will fail because `color is undefined`. I want to know why, and how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the random number:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length+1);
```

It will generate random number between `0` to `colors.length+1` where `colors.length` is `10` so it will generate random numbers between `0-10` and if the random number is `10` then `colors[random];` will give you `undefined` as there is no element in index 10 of `colors` array. Thus,

```
var color = colors[random]; //undefined
return callback(color);  //callback has value undefined
```

To fix this change your code to,

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
```

Which will generate random numbers between `0-9` only.

Comment: @NVO ;-) It happens